# how to turn on GUI mode in google cloud instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud instance, Debian 10 installed there & I can login with SSH.
Now I want to enable GUI mode there, please tell me the steps & please tell me how to login in that google instance using that GUI mode.